# How to fix Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Device>' to expected argument type 'Device'

Tags: swiftui, binding

I am coding up a little app and I need to pass a variable to a function. The problem is that that variable is a binding but the function has to accept a regular variable.

Code:

```
ForEach($deviceArrays.devices, id: \.id) { deviceArray in
     HStack {
          ForEach(deviceArray.row, id: \.id) { device in
               AnotherView(device: $currentDevice, size: $size)
                   .onAppear {
                        setCurrentDevice(to: device)
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

```
func setCurrentDevice(to device: Device) {
    currentDevice = device
}
```

Comment: Can you show code for your `AnotherView`?

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: `setCurrentDevice(to: device)` @George

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that on this line:

```
ForEach($deviceArrays.devices, id: \.id) { deviceArray in
```

You should use `$deviceArray` instead, because you are inputting a `Binding` into the `ForEach`. Then you can access `deviceArray` for the regular value.

---

#### Other solution

Use its `wrappedValue` property.

This converts a type of `Binding<T>` to `T`. In your case, `Binding<Device>` to `Device`.

```
ForEach($deviceArrays.devices, id: \.id) { deviceArray in
     HStack {
          ForEach(deviceArray.row, id: \.id) { device in
               AnotherView(device: $currentDevice, size: $size)
                   .onAppear {
                        setCurrentDevice(to: device.wrappedValue)
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, but shouldn't `device` be just a normal `Device`? Or is part of the new iOS 15 bindings...

Comment: @aheze Seems like they have something like `[[Binding<Device>]]` (with more to it, like `Identifiable` structs). An array of an array of bindings

Comment: @aheze Found the real issue, see edit - it was related to a `Binding` sequence

Comment: Thanks everyone! That did it. My window is still entirely blank though so IDK what's going on haha

Comment: @MarkReggiardo Make sure you already are passing in data. If you rely on `setCurrentDevice` to create the data, you will need to move the `onAppear` higher in the hierarchy, otherwise that code won't be run.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

Double List

Note: CalcButton is Enum: String

```
 let buttons: [[CalcButton]] = [
    [.clear, .negative, .percent, .divide],
    [.seven, .eight, .nine, .mutliply],
    [.four, .five, .six, .subtract],
    [.one, .two, .three, .add],
    [.zero, .decimal, .equal],
]
```

Loop Example:

```
  // Our buttons
            ForEach(buttons, id: \.self) { row in
                HStack(spacing: 12) {
                    ForEach(row, id: \.self) { item in
                        Button(action: {
                            
                            self.didTap(button: item)
                            
                        }, label: {
                            Text(item.rawValue)
                                .font(.system(size: 32))
                                .bold()
                                .frame(
                                    width: self.buttonWidth(item: item),
                                    height: self.buttonHeight()
                                )
                                .background(item.buttonColor)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .cornerRadius(self.buttonWidth(item: item)/2)
                        })
                    }
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 3)
            }
        }
```

Thanks!